# How to get airflow time zone information from macros?

Tags: airflow

**Background**

I am trying to run a DAG at 10pm `America/New_York` once every day from Monday to Friday. The script which the DAG runs takes as input the day it runs on for its 
time zone (10pm Mon-Fri). When I run this scrip as an Airflow DAG, the date is derived from the macro `{{ ds_nodash }}`

**The problem**

When Airflow runs, by the time it's 10pm NY time, it's already the next day on UTC time. Since Airflow uses UTC, the execution date is one day ahead, so when my DAG uses the macro `{{ ds_nodash }}`, it is one day ahead.

**Question:**

Is there a way to get the time-zone adjusted date as a macro on airflow or is the only solution to my problem to adjust the macro myself?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/timezone.html#templates), the default variables (such as `{{ ds_nodash }}`) are in UTC. So, we need to convert them ourselves. It can go something like this:

```
# ...
local_ds_nodash = '{{ dag.timezone.convert(execution_date).strftime("%Y%m%d") }}'
# ...
create_file = BashOperator(
    task_id='create_file',
    bash_command=f'touch {local_ds_nodash}.txt'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that you may mess up with two different concepts in airflow.

1. Actually, 'ds' is not the date which the tasks are running, it is the previous period of tasks running. for example, for ds is 3/25/2019, it would be running on 3/26/2019 rather than 3/25. So if you want your tasks running exactly on Mon-Fri, you need to set the schedule_interval as '0 22 * * 1-5'. The weekday settings should be '1-5' instead of '2-6'.
2. For timezone, kaxil's answer has explained very well. But if for some reason, you cannot change the airflow server configuration, what you need to do is to adjust schedule_interval as '0 2 * * 2-6'. Then the tasks will run as you expected.

Comment: Since the Airflow documentation does not suggest on changing the time zone, I left it as `utc` but added `tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('America/New_York')` per `DAG` in the `args`.
Then when I define for example a schedule_interval as `'0 22 * * 1-5', this will run Mon-Fri at 22:00 New York time, correct or no?

Comment: If you set like this way: `start_date=datetime(2019,3, 23, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('America/New_York'))`, `0 22 * * 1-5` should be ok. But I haven't test it in any chance. So I won't suggest you to do so, as weekday settings may cause some unexpected results in those calculation. Why not just simply use ' 0 2 * * 2-6 '?

Answer (score -1):

Timezone feature is now available in Airflow. Have a look at https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.2/timezone.html and adjust your config in `airflow.cfg` accordingly.

By default it is

```
[core]
default_timezone = utc
```

adjust it to

```
[core]
default_timezone = America/New_York
```

The execution_date will then contain TZ info as well which you would be able to extract. Try it in a test environment before you roll out to your production environment.

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work for me. What worked for me is to define a time zone for each dag. Either way, my question is about how to extract the execution date in a particular time zone.